# Is it possible to fetch IMAP Mails based on precise Date including Hours Minutes Seconds with imap-tool lib?

Tags: python, email, imap, imap-tools

i daily update a list of emails with the imap-tool lib from Python. And because i dont want to "iterate" through all mails in the Inbox, i take the most recent mail in my list and take the date it was received Lastdate, so something like "13-Dec-2023" would stand in the query.

```
 mailbox.folder.set('Inbox') 
    backup_mail_list =[]
    for msg in mailbox.fetch("SINCE 13-Dec-2023"):
```

But i would rather query a more precise date like SINCE 13-Dec-2023 09:49:23 , is that possible ? in the shown format it is not possible

Comment: No.  The search language does not  support it.  See RFC 3501 for details.

Comment: ok yes i thought that, i hoped they might be a work around, it would have made my code a bit faster and then i would have less duplicates to remove

Comment: The work around is to cache locally UIDs you've seen before and ignore them.  Or to only search UIDs.  On a properly implemented server, UIDs only ever go up (unless it resets the UIDVALIDITY)

Comment: i could try uid i already save UID of the messages i receive the problem is that like 8 people have acess to the Mail Account and they do sometimes accidentally move or remove emails so that the UID of the old Mails are changes , i mean that still should be doable, like just fetching Mails with a UID bigger than the lastUID -3 or so, how would i write in this in the criteria of fetch ?

Comment: If they move it out, and move it back, it will get a new UID, unless your server is extremely broken.